# bar plot in r with multiple bars per x variable

Tags: r, bar-chart

How do I plot a bar-plot so that every variable (treatment group) on the x-axis displays two bars, representing avgRDm and avgSDM? I would like the bars to be colored by avgRDm and avgSDM. 
The data for the plot is in the following image:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of `ggplot`, so here is an option in that vein. It's easiest (and tidiest) to reshape data from wide to long and then map the `fill` aesthetic to the `key`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    gather(key, val, -trt) %>%
    ggplot(aes(trt, val, fill = key)) +
    geom_col(position = "dodge2")
```

[image]

PS. For future posts, please share data in a reproducible way using e.g. `dput`; screenshots are never a good idea as it requires respondents to manually type out your sample data.

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
"trt    avgRDM  avgSDM
F10    49.5    108.333
NH4Cl   12.583  50.25
NH4NO3  17.333  73.33
'F10 + ANU843'    6.0 7.333", header = T)
```

Comment: For base: `barplot(t(df[,2:3]), beside = TRUE, names.arg = df$trt)`